# how to choose between two queries

Tags: php, mysql

```
$user_query = mysql_query("select * from student where student_id='$session_id'") or die(mysql_error());
$user_query = mysql_query("select * from teacher where teacher_id='$session_id'") or die(mysql_error());
$user_row = mysql_fetch_array($user_query);
$params["nick"] = $user_row['firstname']." ".$user_row['lastname'];
```

I am working on a chat forum where both the lecturer and student have access to that page. `$params["nick"]` is the name assigned to the user who visits that page based on the `session_id`. since both the lecturer and student can access the page, I would like to choose between the two queries so that if is a student, the first query is executed or if is a lecturer, the second query is executed.

Comment: You can't because you overwrite the variable!

Comment: How do you know if it's a teacher or a lecturer?

Comment: put those 2 queries in an if php wont magically mix them

Comment: Use [if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Comment: @BeatAlex the session_id for lecturer's start from 1000001 and that of student from 1

Comment: `PHP` is removing `mysql` at the end of the year, use `PDO` or `mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you're overwriting your variable so it's always going to be getting it from the `teacher` table.

What you need to do is get a way of differentiating if the user is a teacher or a student.

Then do an `if` statement.

```
if ($session_id >= 100000){
    $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE teacher_id='$session_id'");
} else {
    $user_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_id='$session_id'");
}
```

Then the `$user_query` isn't overwritten and is one or the other.

Then you can do your `$user_row = mysql_fetch_array($user_query);`

**As a side note:**

Do not use `mysql_*` anymore! It is not good code! Please look at `mysqli_*` or `PDO` and prepared statements!

Comment: the session_id for lecturer's start from 1000001 and that of student from 1.

Comment: shouldn't it be the other way round .ie. the query for the teacher first else the query for the student.

Comment: You're right @IndicesLogEbenezerCalculus I got my more than and less than mixed up sorry!

Answer (score 0):

A bad way of doing it, but can work, since you doesn't sounds like you know if the user is a teacher or student before you've made the query.

```
$user_query = mysql_query("select * from student where student_id='$session_id'") or die(mysql_error());
$user_row = mysql_fetch_array($user_query);
if (mysql_num_rows($user_query) == 1) {
    $params["nick"] = $user_row['firstname']." ".$user_row['lastname'];
} else {
    $user_query = mysql_query("select * from teacher where teacher_id='$session_id'") or die(mysql_error());
    $user_row = mysql_fetch_array($user_query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($user_query) == 1) {
        $params["nick"] = $user_row['firstname']." ".$user_row['lastname'];
    }
}
```

If i were you, i would make a new table that has the userid, and is storing if it's a teacher or student, and then have all the users in the same table.